# "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

Tags: bug, reputation, comments

I am really, really angry with the ridiculous "reputation" system which disallows just about anything.

I want to improve posts by commenting - thus building actual reputation -, yet there is no way 'cause your fake "reputation" system is in the way.

Oh, and I'm not allowed to use harsh language to describe all this, right? Even though it would be appropriate. Who made you the arbiter of all this? Learn to accept free language, [harsh word here]. I want a FREE site for knowledge exchange.

Comment: "Who made you the arbiter of all this?" Stack Overflow built the Stack Exchange network, and runs it at no cost to the users; they do have a right to place some restrictions on its use. I know you're frustrated by the hurdle, but please understand that there are good reasons for it (e.g. dissuading spammers).

Comment: One doesn't "build actual reputation" by commenting. Ask on-topic questions, post answers - in less than a day you'll get the 50 points you need. Whining, kicking and screaming won't help you. Getting to work will.

Comment: If your plan to gain reputation is to submit comments in order to improve existing questions and answers, your plan is going to result in exactly, 0 reputation being earned.  Comments do not earn you anything.  Improving existing questions and answers by fixing things like grammatical mistakes is one simple way of earning reputation.  You could also find a question, you know the answer to, and submit an high-quality answer to it.  Be sure the answer isn't something that's already been stated otherwise you likely to lose reputation.

Comment: > they do have a right to place some restrictions on its use. <

No they don't. Americans took our ability to communicate to each other which we had before they lured us to their "exchange places".

Comment: > One doesn't "build actual reputation" by commenting. <

How stupid and completely wrong.

Answer (score 11):

The reputation threshold for commenting is set high to limit the volume of comments and reduce spamming. Comments in particular are a burden to site moderators, which are community users volunteering their time.

You can earn reputation by making good edits, asking good questions, and submitting good answers. All these actions are available to users, whatever their reputation. If you want to be in a club then you have to play by the rules of that club. The club is the arbiter.

It is never appropriate to use bad language, particularly in writing. I hope you can work through your anger in time.

Comment: >  Comments in particular are a burden to site moderators

How about adding AI? I can do that.